# Tomcat 7 and Grails deployment - what should the conf/web.xml look like?

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, grails

I have added this to my `web.xml` file in Tomcat:

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>GroovyTemplate</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.gsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But I get this from Catalina:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name GroovyTemplate
```

The problem is that it will not load the manager anymore or any other apache tools that come with it.

But also if I do not have that in my `web.xml` then my Grails app will not start and returns a 404 error.

So what is the correct set up of the `web.xml` for grails app?

This is how it looks now (part of it):

```
<!-- The mapping for the default servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- The mappings for the JSP servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>GroovyTemplate</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.gsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: As I deployed my grails app I just called 'grails war' to create a war and then put it in tomcat container. Did you tried that? My generated web.xml contains <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>gsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check out file yourGrailsProject/target/work/web.xml.tmp or here: https://github.com/wshearn/grails-test/blob/master/target/web.xml.tmp
where you can find sections like:

```
<!-- The Groovy Server Pages servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

which contain full path to GroovyPagesServlet.